# Laravel 8: Markdown editor does not seem to be working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to make an Online Forum and in this project, I used [this](https://packagist.org/packages/michelf/php-markdown) package which is a Markdown Editor for questions that come with codes.

So I ran `composer require michelf/php-markdown` and after installation completed, I tried to use it by saying:

```
<div class="thread-details">
    {!! \Michelf\Markdown::defaultTransform($thread->thread)  !!}
</div>
```

But now the problem is, it returns nothing as output!

So how can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this with me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable autoloading ..
What i did was i ran

```
composer require michelf/php-markdown
```

Then in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` i included...

```
return array(
...
    'Michelf\\' => array($vendorDir.'/michelf/php-markdown/Michelf'),
);
```

Then inside controller

```
  <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Michelf\Markdown;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
    class ListController extends Controller
    {
    public function index (){
            $my_html = Markdown::defaultTransform('*normal emphasis with asterisks*');
        
        $my_html1 = Markdown::defaultTransform('_normal emphasis with underscore_');       
        $my_html2 = Markdown::defaultTransform('**strong emphasis with asterisks**');
        $my_html3 = Markdown::defaultTransform('__strong emphasis with underscore__');
        $my_html4 = Markdown::defaultTransform('This is some text *emphased* with asterisks.');
        echo $my_html;
        echo $my_html1;
        echo $my_html2;

        echo $my_html3;

        echo $my_html4;
    }
    }
```

In web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ListController;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/markdown',[ListController::class,'index']);
```

Then i ran php artisan serve

and i got...
[image]

Comment: @tejoslaeslio  did this help you ..please reply... if it did help you please upvote the answer and give me a like,,,

Comment: Yes it did help. Thank u :)

Comment: @tejoslaeslio glad that i could help you... welcome.

Comment: But I also want to add markdown editor to my `textarea`  at form (when I want to add question details) just like stack overflow, that you can choose your text to be **bold** or *italic* or `code`. How can I add those buttons to textarea field ?

Comment: I think you need something like a tinymce editor...please check this...https://medium.com/@bvipul/integrate-tinymce-editor-in-your-laravel-installation-with-a-filemanager-235894910531

Comment: please have alook at this too..https://nadjmandev.com/integrate-tinymce-editor-in-laravel-with-a-file-manager-image-upload/  Did it help you...

Comment: Those are WYSIWYG editors that can add headings or paragraphs and etc. But Stackoverflow uses Markdown editors which are different!

Comment: yes this seems to be what stackoverflow is using .  https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp   ...but it is implemented in c#

Comment: Yeah stack is written in C#. But thanks anyway.

Comment: but if you want tinymce you could better use text pattern plugins  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/plugins/textpattern/